# Unable to play youtube tracks using wavelink, convert function is not working either

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is my sample code for testing running a youtube link, I've tried a lot of permutations and combinations of the functions in the wavelink library however it always comes back as need an AudioSource to play not YoutubeTrack. my main goal is to play spotify songs on a lowkey server but the Youtube functionality isn't working either

```
@bot.command(name='spotify', help='To resume song')
async def resume(ctx):
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjGkbFqi67c"
    server = ctx.message.guild
    vc: wavelink.Player = server.voice_client

    query = f'ytsearch:{url}'

    tracks = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query)
    track = tracks[0]
    audio_source = await track.convert(ctx, url)
    await vc.play(audio_source)
```